# Smartctl reporting read failure for block -- How to mark as 'don't use'?

Tags: smart

On one of my hard disc I've got a bad test result from smart like this:

```
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     19889         128652505
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%     19882         128652505
```

As from my understanding, this means "only" that there are some bad blocks, how to mark them as don't use? This disk is running inside an software raid.

Comment: It "only" means that it's time to replace the disk. Assuming you actually want to keep your data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't do this. You replace the disk because it's starting to fail and you don't want that to happen. The disk firmware manages bad blocks (and have spare ones to map into place for the ones it sort's out), so if you get read errors reported, things are bad.

Comment: OK. gonna change the hard disc.